# Variable arguments in Typescript, but no array / list

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.8

Is there any way to have variable arguments in Typescript that are not wrapped in an array? The only syntax I know is:

```
protected log(...args: any[]): void
```

Not really a problem but time consuming and unnecessary clicks are the result. If you are passing `args` e.g. to console.log the output is a collapsible "object", like `|> [Array[2]]`. Expanded, there is unneeded, nested text and prototype information, s.th. like

```
v [Array[2]]
    0:Array[2]
       0:"Blah"
    |> 1:input
       length:2
 |> __proto__:Array[0]
    length:1
 |> __proto__:Array[0]
```

You have to click every single entry to read the log completely or to search an entry. This is no fun compared to the output of real array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or objects:

```
|> Object {a1: "123", b1: 456, c1: 789, a2: "123", b2: 456…}
```

They provide a kind of summary and the expanded version is also alphabetically sorted:

```
a1:"123"
a2:"123"
a3:"123"
b1:456
b2:456
b3:456
c1:789
c2:789
c3:789
```

For sure, it is possible to to `iterate` argument members or using a `reduce` function. But besides unnecessary code and logic just for more comfortable logging output seams to be overhead with higher costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arrays you can do something like:

```
function log() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}
```

Then:

```
log(1); // 1
log(1, 2, 3); // 1 2 3
log([1, 2, 3]); // > [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The trick to use apply seams to be a kind of workaround, but if using external logger, there is the need to patch it to use apply.

Comment: You probably won't find a solution that does not require a workaround or implement a formatter yourself

Comment: If the external logger does not expose a function that you can call in order to log it's a pretty odd logger.  `apply` is a method on `Function.prototype` and will be available no matter what logger you are using.

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer the trick to use apply fullfills our requirements. As we are using a delegator class for the logger, we can use apply there. Then we could read the log without the need to expand every node to what happens there. And for detailed information there is still the possibility to look deeper into a node.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no alternative syntax to accept a variable number of arguments. This sounds like your browser/console is just outputting too much unnecessary information. Mine—chrome—just outputs the values surrounded in brackets.

If you want something quick, then you can just do this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
```

Or create your own function for outputting the array to your liking.

Comment: Ok stringify is not option, the output is single line in console and even harder to read.  Currently we use a custom function to prepare output. But it would be much nicer and cleaner if there are any built in possibilities.